# WPF ribbonwindow on windows 8 Desktop developer preview

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, windows-8

Tried testing my [ribbonwindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff703716.aspx) in windows 8 developer preview and found out that mostly everything functions OK except the minimize , maximize and close ribbonwindow buttons are missing ! 
Does anyone know how to get these back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no window style present this occurs. You need to specify : WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"  in the ribbonwindow.